Neovim Python semantic syntax highlighting not working
I got Neovim recently. I am using init.vim and Vim plug. I am trying to get semantic highlighting working in Python3 files. For example, in Typescript when I call this.get_card("df", dfinfo), the this and get_card and dfinfo all get highlighted in purple, yellow, and blue respectively. But in Python, when I use self.get_card("df", dfinfo), self, get_card, and dfinfo are all just the text color. Both times, the "df" part gets highlighted brown. Also, the type checking works but not the semantic syntax highlighting. Like when I do unused_var = "hello", the blue block and some text says that it's unused. The syntax highlighting is just not working. Here is some of my init.vim:
call plug#begin()
Plug 'Mofiqul/vscode.nvim'
Plug 'neovim/nvim-lspconfig'
call plug#end()

color vscode

lua << EOF

require'lspconfig'.tsserver.setup{}
require'lspconfig'.pyright.setup{}

EOF


Never mind, it's impossible. Apparently, Pyright and most other Neovim LSPs don't provide semantic syntax highlighting... (https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/14trkmh/how_do_you_enable_semantic_highlighting_for_python/)
